# Inner product: prove $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on a vector space $V$, and define, for each ordered pair of vectors, the scalar $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$, called distance between $x$ and $y$. Prove the following results for all $x,y,z\in V$.

$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$$

I tried to prove this in different ways, I tried to prove  $\|x-y\|^{2}\leq (||x-z|| + ||z-y||)^{2}$ and expanded everything out, move this and that around, but none of my tactics work. Please give me some insight or trick of how to prove this. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use the triangular inequality for the norm?

Comment: do I need to first prove $d(x,y) \geq 0 $ in order to use the triangular inequality?

Comment: What does this have to do with [inner products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)?

Comment: Write $\|x-y\| = \|(x-z) + (z-y)\| \leq \|x-z\|+\|y-z\|$.

Comment: Inner products have nothing to do with your work. Is better you say a metric on V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the axioms of a norm in hand, then as first comment states, it follows from $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$.  Here $a$ is the displacement from $x$ to $y$ and $b$ the displacement from $y$ to $z$.

If the norm is defined from the inner product and you want to check that $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$, the square of that inequality is equivalent to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $(a . b) \leq |a||b|$.